# Why the ASCII value of a digit character is equal to the value plus '0'?

Tags: c, ascii

Why when we want to convert an ASCII value of a digit into an integer, we need to do:

`value - '0'` ?

And the other way around, to convert Integer to ASCII, we need to do:

```
value + '0'
```

Why is that?

Comment: Note: Both of thes assume the integer in question is between zero (0) and nine (9). only in that range is this accurate.

Comment: ASCII is an irrelevance: this conversion is true for portable C code, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Because the integral values of the digit characters are guaranteed by the C standard to be consecutive.**

Therefore `'1' - '0' == 1`, `'2' - '0' == 2`, etc. from which you can infer that your formulas really do work.

Sidenotes:

1. Since this is guaranteed by the standard, it works even if the target platform does not use ASCII.
2. Conversely, if the standard did not mandate this (it does not do so with the values of the letters) then this technique would not be portable; it would be dependent on the target system using ASCII.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the ASCII standard is irrelevant. The C standard itself guarantees that numbers '0' to '9' are adjacent: those are the only characters that the standard makes any form on guarantee about.

Answer (score 3):

Because ASCII digits are encoded consequently one after another.

Say `'0' == 48`. Then `'1' == 49`, `'2' == 50` and so on.

If you think about it, `'2' - '0' == 50 - 48 == 2`. Similarly, `2 + '0' == 2 + 48 == 50 == '2'`.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII values of the digits are all in sequence. So `0` simply marks the start of the sequence at ASCII codepoint `48`, continuing up to `9` at position `57`.

Answer (score 0):

Just because codes of digits are in sequence (48 .. 57) as defined by ASCII [standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Answer (score 0):

ASCII value is a position number of a symbol in the table. So you use '0' symbol position number as an offset of the digit symbols, adding an integer digit value to it you can calculate its position number.