# Evaluating a postfix expression

Tags: c++

This is a program to evaluate a post-fix expression using stack. Why in the *8th* line we have pushed **question[i]-'0'** rather than just **question[i]**. I did not understand the role of 0.

```cpp
stack<int> s;
int main(){
  string question;
  cin>>question;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < question.length() ; i++){
    if(isdigit(question[i]))
      s.push(question[i] - '0');
    else{
      int a = s.top();
      s.pop();
      int b = s.top();
      s.pop();

      if(question[i]=='+') s.push(a+b);
      else if(question[i]=='-') s.push(a-b);
      else if(question[i]=='*') s.push(a*b);
      else if(question[i]=='/') s.push(a/b);
    }
  }
  cout<<"Converting to infix and solving we get : "<<s.top();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'7'` is not the same as `7`. To convert, subtract the character code of `'0'` to get the index == the numerical value.

Comment: [convert char to int number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c) could help

Comment: similarly, [Why the ASCII value of a digit character is equal to the value plus '0'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831638/why-the-ascii-value-of-a-digit-character-is-equal-to-the-value-plus-0)

Comment: Understood. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'0'` is a [**character literal**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal).

So when you wrote:

```
s.push(question[i] - '0');
```

The **fundamental reason** why/how `question[i] - '0'` works is through [**promotion**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).
In particular,

> both `question[i]` and `'0'` will be **promoted to `int`**. And the final result that is pushed onto the stack named `s` will be the result of **subtraction** of those two **promoted** `int` values.

Also note that the [**C++ Standard (2.3 Character sets)**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.charset) guarantees that:

> 3. ...In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
>    each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>    one greater than the value of the previous.

For example, say we have:

```
std::string question = "123";
int a = question[0] - '0'; //the result of question[0] - '0' is guaranteed to be the integer 1
int b = question[1] - '0'; //the result of question[1] - '0' is guaranteed to be the integer 2
int c = question[2] - '0'; //the result of question[2] - '0' is guaranteed to be the integer 3
```

Lets consider the statement `int a = question[0] - '0';`:

Here both `question[0]` and `0` will be promoted to `int`. And the final result that is used to **initialize** variable `a` on the left hand side will be the result of subtraction of those two promoted int values on the right hand side. Moreover, the result is guaranteed to be the integer `1`.

Similarly, for statement `int b = question[1] - '0';`:

Here both `question[1]` and `0` will be promoted to `int`. And the final result that is used to **initialize** variable `b` on the left hand side will be the result of subtraction of those two promoted int values on the right hand side. Moreover, the result is guaranteed to be the integer `2`.

And similarly for variable `c`.